# UITypeEditor no funciona en .NET 6.0

Tags: c#, .net

Estoy bastante confundido con un código que en su momento funcionaba perfectamente en .NET Framework 4.8. Ahora estoy implementando un control personalizado en .NET 6.0 y he incorporado una propiedad *LineStyle* a dicho control que dispone de un editor personalizado. El código de dicha propiedad es el siguiente:

```
[DefaultValue(DashStyle.Solid)]
[Editor(typeof(LineStyleEditor), typeof(UITypeEditor))]
public DashStyle LineStyle
{
   get { return m_LineStyle; }
   set
   {
      m_LineStyle = value;
      NotifyPropertyChanged();
   }
}
```

Y ahora el código para el editor personalizado donde nos saldría un desplegable con los tipos de líneas sería el siguiente:

```
public class LineStyleEditor : UITypeEditor
{
    // Indicate that we display a dropdown.
    public override UITypeEditorEditStyle GetEditStyle(ITypeDescriptorContext? context)
    {
        return UITypeEditorEditStyle.DropDown;
    }

    // Edit a line style

    public override object? EditValue(ITypeDescriptorContext? context, IServiceProvider? provider, Object? value)
    {
        Type serviceType = typeof(IWindowsFormsEditorService);

        // Get an IWindowsFormsEditorService object.
        if (provider != null)
        {
            IWindowsFormsEditorService editor_service = (IWindowsFormsEditorService)provider.GetService(serviceType);

            
            // Convert the value into a BorderStyles value.
            if (value != null && editor_service != null)
            {
                DashStyle line_style = (DashStyle)value;

                // Make the editing control.
                using (LineStyleListBox editor_control = new LineStyleListBox(line_style, editor_service, Color.Red))
                {
                    // Display the editing control.
                    editor_service.DropDownControl(editor_control);
                    // Save the new results.
                    return (DashStyle)editor_control.SelectedIndex;
                }
            }
        }

        return base.EditValue(context, provider, value);
    }

    // Indicate that we draw values in the Properties window.
    public override bool GetPaintValueSupported(ITypeDescriptorContext context)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public override void PaintValue(PaintValueEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Value != null)
        {
            HatchStyle hatch = (HatchStyle)e.Value;

            // Draw the sample.
            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.White, e.Bounds);
            DrawSamplePen(e.Graphics, e.Bounds, Color.Black, (DashStyle)e.Value);
        }
    }
    static private void DrawSamplePen(Graphics g, Rectangle p_Rect, Color p_LineColor, DashStyle p_DashStyle)
    {
        int y = p_Rect.Y + p_Rect.Height / 2;

        using (Pen l_Pen = new Pen(p_LineColor, 2))
        {
            l_Pen.DashStyle = p_DashStyle;
            g.DrawLine(l_Pen, p_Rect.Left + 1, y, p_Rect.Right - 1, y);
        }
    }
}
```

La lista desplegable personalizada la tenemos en el siguiente código:

```
[ToolboxItem(false)]
public class LineStyleListBox: ListBox
{
    private Color LineColor { get; set; } = Color.Black;

    private IWindowsFormsEditorService m_EditorService;
    public LineStyleListBox(DashStyle p_DashStyle, IWindowsFormsEditorService editor_service, Color p_Color)
    {
        m_EditorService = editor_service;

        // Make items for each LineStyles value.
        for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
            Items.Add(i);

        LineColor = p_Color;
        // Select the current line style.
        SelectedIndex = (int)p_DashStyle;

        DrawMode = DrawMode.OwnerDrawFixed;
        ItemHeight = 18;
        this.Click += LineStyleListBox_Click;
        this.DrawItem += LineStyleListBox_DrawItem;
    }

    private void LineStyleListBox_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (m_EditorService != null)
            m_EditorService.CloseDropDown();
    }

    private void LineStyleListBox_DrawItem(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e)
    {
        DrawSamplePen(e.Graphics, e.Bounds, Color.Black, (DashStyle)e.Index);
    }

    static private void DrawSamplePen(Graphics g, Rectangle p_Rect, Color p_LineColor, DashStyle p_DashStyle)
    {
        int y = p_Rect.Y + p_Rect.Height / 2;

        using (Pen l_Pen = new Pen(p_LineColor, 2))
        {
            l_Pen.DashStyle = p_DashStyle;
            g.DrawLine(l_Pen, p_Rect.Left + 1, y, p_Rect.Right - 1, y);
        }
    }
}
```

Toda la problemática gira entorno a que no puedo visualizar el editor en la ventana propiedades del control. Lo que obtengo es como se ve en la imagen un ListBox normal y no el personalizado.

[image: Propiedad LineStyle]

Llevo muchas horas mirando y revisando y no da errores pero tampoco se comporta como se espera, no sé si será de algún problema de configuración o no. A ver si alguien pueda saber a qué se debe. Lo que espero es un desplegable algo así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Saludos y gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Desde .net Core hubo cambios importantes a la hora de crear controles personalizados y campos personalizados.

Si ocupas los derivados preexistentes de [UITypeEditor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.design.uitypeeditor?view=windowsdesktop-7.0) no debes hacer nada adicional, por ejemplo para

- BinaryEditor
- CollectionEditor
- DateTimeEditor
- MultilineStringEditor
- ObjectSelectorEditor
- ColorEditor
- ImageEditor
- ETC

Es decir puedes crear en tu control personalizado un campo `Color` y usar `ColorEditor`, o un campo `DateTime` y usar `DateTimeEditor`. Esto de igual manera que lo venias haciendo siempre.

Ahora si quieres crear un personalizado derivando de `UITypeEditor` eso ya no se puede hacer de la manera que tu lo estas haciendo.

Y tal como tu lo has comprobado no arroja error alguno, pero no llama a tu editor personalizado y solo muestra el editor default, que para tu caso (un `enum`) sería una lista con los nombres de cada elemento.

---

La forma nueva de crear componente personalizado junto con el editor de tipo, es un enredo de magnitudes que nunca antes había visto. Al pasar los años he visto como lamentablemente Microsoft difuculta lo que siempre hizo facil, pero ahora creo que se le pasó la mano

Debes bajar un SDK y las plantillas necesarias, y luego crear una serie de proyectos:

- **Control**: este proyecto es la biblioteca de controles personalizada que contiene el código de los controles. Esta es la biblioteca a la que un usuario haría referencia cuando quiera usar los controles.
- **Control.Client**: un proyecto de formularios Windows Forms para .NET Framework que contiene los cuadros de diálogo de interfaz de usuario del diseñador personalizado.
- **Control.Server**: un proyecto de formularios Windows Forms para .NET que contiene el código de diseñador personalizado para los controles.
- **Control.Protocol**: un proyecto de .NET Standard que contiene las clases de comunicación utilizadas por los proyectos
- **Control.Package**: un proyecto de paquete NuGet que contiene todos los demás proyectos. Este paquete tiene un formato que permite que Visual Studio Windows Forms para .NET Tooling hospede y use la biblioteca de controles y los diseñadores.

Y por supuesto cada proyecto tienes sus cositas.

Mas información en

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/controls-design/designer-differences-framework?view=netdesktop-7.0

https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/custom-controls-for-winforms-out-of-process-designer/

Comment: Vaya! con Microsoft. Es sólo un editor para obtener unos valores en tiempo de diseño del control. Sería bueno que en un único archivo se pudiera crear el Editor compilase en el Framework del IDE, una librería de editores personalizados y que independientemente de la plataforma en la que yo cree mi control, VS importara esa porción de código para poder mostrar el editor personalizado en la ventana de propiedades. Luego para la funcionalidad del control una vez ubicado en la aplicación destino compilada no es necesario ese código. No entiendo que complicasen todo tanto. Gracias por tu respuesta.

Comment: @AntonioS.F. Yo tampoco entiendo la necesidad de complicar todo. De lo que investigué se debe a que ahora .net es multiplataforma y por eso necesitaban cambiar el asunto. Pero que la aplicación resultante sea multiplataforma no tiene que ver con el "Editor" en que se ha creado, editor que es monoplataforma...no me hace sentido. En mi opinión personal, pasa que Microsoft ha querido matar a WinForm desde hace años, ha creado una serie de reemplazantes como WPF, UWP y MAUI y es por eso que no pone mucho esfuerzo en mejorar WinForm. Y lo entiendo, Winforms tiene demasiados años